# How to install LibreOffice? (replacing OpenOffice.org)

Tags: libreoffice, software-installation, openoffice.org

On 10.10 how do I get rid of Openoffice.org, and install LibreOffice without borking my system?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is an [official LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ppa) for Ubuntu 10.10 and 10.04 (the upcoming 11.04 will have LibreOffice by default).

You need to add `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` in your software sources to add it to the software center, just follow the [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) for the GUI way.

#### Quick and dirty CLI instructions (these will remove OpenOffice.org):

Add the PPA and install LibreOffice:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

For GNOME integration (for people running default Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gnome
```

or for KDE Integration (for people running Kubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-kde
```

[Fabian Rodriguez adds](http://www.fabianrodriguez.com/blog/2011/01/25/the-document-foundation-launches-libreoffice-3-3):

> If you are using Ubuntu do not download the .deb files for manual installation, there is a PPA repository that has been available for a few weeks now. Follow these instructions to install LibreOffice from the PPA so you get automatic updates.
>
> Keep in mind a PPA is always considered a third-party application and unfit for production purposes, however LibreOffice is becoming part of Ubuntu officially in the next release, due in April 2011, so the PPA will get a lot of attention and care. Make sure you test this and perhaps wait a few weeks if you intend to use this in 10.04 LTS or 10.10 in any significant way.
>
> Additional language modules, help files and extensions are also available if you search for libreoffice in your package manager.

[If you get an "unmet dependencies" error, you probably need to uninstall openoffice (the installation of LibreOffice will continue automatically immediately after openoffice is purged from the system)]
sudo apt-get purge "openoffice*.*"

[Also note: I got an error about Java : you may want to check that is installed before installing LibreOffice]

Comment: LibreOffice 3.3 Final (2011-01-25) release is bit-for-bit identical to the Release Candidate 4, so you don't need to download or reinstall if you have that version already.  http://www.libreoffice.org/download/release-notes/

Answer (score 8):

As described in the [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1585017), you need to remove the OpenOffice packages with

```
sudo apt-get remove openoffice*.*
```

Download LibreOffice from: [LibreOffice Downloads](http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/testing/)

Extract the file to ~/Desktop

Rename the file to libreoffice

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/libreoffice/DEBS/*.deb

sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/libreoffice/DEBS/desktop-integration/libreoffice3.3-debian-menus_3.3-9526_all.deb
```

Comment: Those with locales other than English should replace the word "Desktop" in the commands with whatever name they use for Desktop. Also, the into account that the name of the file "libreoffice3.3-debian-menus_3.3-9526_all.deb" has changed in 3.3.0 Beta 2 to "libreoffice3.3-debian-menus_3.3-1_all.deb" As an easy alternative: After you extract the file open a terminal in the newly created directory (in this case no need to rename) and run the command **sudo dpkg -i *.deb** Then open a terminal in the directory which is also in the directory (named "desktop-integration"), run the same command.

Comment: If you want to install your locale language packs, download your language pack from the same place you downloaded LibreOffice, extract the file init, open a terminal in the newly created directory, run **sudo dpkg -i *.deb**

Comment: I used the PPA, but removing OpenOffice is a very good idea (I used 'sudo apt-get purge openoffice*.*)