# Why does LibreOffice look old?

Tags: appearance, libreoffice

Why does LibreOffice look like this? Looks old...

[image]

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so can you accept the answer? (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 27):

You probably need to install `libreoffice-gnome`

- [How to install LibreOffice? (replacing OpenOffice.org)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7373/how-to-install-libreoffice-replacing-openoffice-org)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I just googled the exact same thing. To get a modern look for kde just do install `libreoffice-kde`. Why this is not standard, I have no idea

`apt install libreoffice-kde`

[image]