# Greek Letters rendered incorrectly in LibreOffice

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

Using an old archive that I have (with Maxwell's equations), the Greek letters display as *squares*. I tried to change something in the alphabet but even the fonts don't have any Greek letters (they appear like squares too), both Greek and iGreek letters packages.

Sounds like a package that's not installed, or corrupted. I still re-downloaded and reinstalled LibreOffice. I don't know what I have to install. The equations look fine in OpenOffice.org (I made the file with it). What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to everybody that helped me, but I figured out how to solve my problem. I installed the LibreOffice via the deb in its page after completely remove my OO. When I did that i removed too the package "ttf-opensymbol".

When I [installed the LibreOffice PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7373/how-to-install-libreoffice-replacing-openoffice-org/20685#20685) this package was installed automatically. But I will communicate them about this issue (they should include this dependence in their "how to install" pages).

Answer (score 0):

You need to report this bug to the LibreOffice project:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/

Comment: Thank you. I solved it and I'll use your links to communicate them about the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Gucharmap (Characters map) to copy greek characters and paste them on LibreOffice? With Gucharmap you can also see if a font render them right.